# How to set attributes of a long list of times in a shorter way?

Tags: python, django

I have to do something like this

```
class AuthTestings(TestClass):
    def setUp(self):
        ...
        self.user = user
        self.user2 = user2
        self.token = token
        self.token2 = token2
        self.myval = myval
        ...
    def test_smth(self):
        ...
#and .....
```

- **my goal** to get a shorter way to do to add attributes to self.
- maybe I can use `setattr`
- or any other way that shorten the job for me

```
from varname.helpers import Wrapper

x =  [user,user2,user3,token,token2,token3,client]
    for i in x:
        i = Wrapper(i)
        setattr(self,i.name,i.value) # this don't work att al because i.name return i instead of user, user2...
```

Comment: one way would be to use `eval`, like `eval(f"self.{i.name}={i.value}")`

Comment: better to use a dictionary instead of a list

Comment: the issue is `i.name` return i instead of use, user2...

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo like `[['user':user}...` that will be painful for my hands

Comment: `{'user':user}`

Comment: the key difference is this, in a list, only the `values` are important, but in a dictionary, you are facing with a `key` and a `value`. if not, consider if you have this: `[user, user]`, what should you do?

Comment: Don't use eval. Please.

Comment: What is the more general problem you are trying to solve, and why?

Comment: Should the code run as part of class `__init__`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, as mentioned in the comments, is to use a dictionary:

```py
d = {'user': user, 'user2': user2, ...}
for name, value in d.items():
    setattr(self, name, value)
```

---

Another solution is to lookup the names in the `globals()` or `locals()` namespaces: (from your question it's unclear whether these are local or global variables)

```py
x = ['user', 'user2', ...]
for name in x:
    setattr(self, name, locals()[name])
```